# change section text uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm looking for a way to change the title of the `section headers` in a `UITableView`. I have been looking at the web and this forum and can't find an answer. Most topics of this nature revolves around changing fonts and colors of the `section header title`.

So, the tableview is populated with let's say, **3 sections: Section 1, Section 2, Section 3**. Now how can I change those titles to whatever I would like?

Philip

Answer (score 0):

You can change the UITableView Section title as below

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *name;
    switch (section)
        {
        case 0:
            name = firstHeader;
            break;
        case 1:
            name =  secondHeader;
            break;

        default:
            name = @"";
            break;
    }    
    return name;
}
```

**Update:**
when you receive your modification for any section in the UITableView why dont you call this method to update the Section

```
 - (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

This will update the Selected section with nice animation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I realized I didn't explain myself clear enough. I'm looking for a way to edit the titles dynamically, in the app itself. So that at any given time a user can change the title of the section header if he wants to. I have already implemented the titleForHeaderInSection: method and everything in my app concerning the sectioned tableview works well.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking that when a user taps the header view, a view pops up with a textfield to edit the title. Then closing the view will show the new title for the given section. I can get the view to appear and close, but I'm not sure how to change the title in code. What would the code look like?

Comment: call a method when the Popup view is closing after taking input from the user then use this for updating
if it is first section
`firstSection = textField.text;
[self reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:(as per your requirement)];`

Comment: I have this code, but it doesn't change the title. The `title`variable is of the type `NSString`. `NSLog(@"New Title: %@", textField.text);
 title = textField.text;
 [tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];`

Comment: What have you implemented in `titleForHeaderInSection` does this method `- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
` is calling after you entering

Comment: titleForHeaderInSection: `return [bookmarks objectAtIndex:section];`. bookmarks is an NSArray.

Comment: where are you updating the title in that method, you should probably update the NSArray or use same as i said in the answer

Comment: I don't believe I need to update the array since I have replaced the bookmarks' titles with custom UILabel titles in `viewForHeaderInSection:`. And then it hit me that if I move the code that gives the sections a title to `titleForHeaderInSection:` as you showed (misread it) it updates. However, now it always updates the title of the first section when I use this code `reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]`

Comment: Should we move this discussion to email? So that it doesn't get to long.